# Crystal C bindings: return type char*

Tags: crystal-lang

I have a function with this signature:

```
const char* get_version();
```

My declaration is:

```
fun get_version(): LibC::Char*
```

And to use it:

```
version = MyLib.get_version()
puts version # how to convert to String?
```

How can I manage the return string? Do I have to import also strlen to measure the length of the C string and covert it to Crystal string manually?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You wrap the `Char*` pointer with `String.new(MyLib.version)`. If you know the string length, you may call `String.new(ptr, size)` too.

Note that this will copy the data from the pointer, so the C binding may release its pointer without affecting the Crystal String.

Comment: Also, one probably wants to delete the pointer manually, only in case the source expects caller to do.